# Trouble when changing Spring Boot version from 2.0.3.RELEASE to 2.1.0.M4

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I have a working code that stops to work when I change Spring Boot version from 2.0.3.RELEASE to  2.1.0.M4

The error is:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'dataSource', defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

A kinda similar question ([Trouble when changing Spring Boot version from 2.0.3.RELEASE to 2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367566/trouble-when-changing-spring-boot-version-from-2-0-3-release-to-2-1-0-build-snap)) was already asked but no proper answer was given.

Following is my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>***.***.***</groupId>
        <artifactId>******</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <artifactId>*****</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>TEST</description>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>${maven.version}</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <start-class>c*.*.Application</start-class>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.2.0</junit.jupiter.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-rsa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Sql server driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring REST Docs dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-webtestclient</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Auto REST Docs dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>capital.scalable</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-auto-restdocs-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit Jupiter API and Engine -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/mockwebserver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor/reactor-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockserver-netty</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.yml</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.jks</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.jks</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.yml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.ekryd.sortpom</groupId>
                <artifactId>sortpom-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeFromFailureFile>${project.basedir}/exclude-pmd.properties</excludeFromFailureFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.gaul</groupId>
                <artifactId>modernizer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>qa</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>qa</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>eclipse</id>
            <dependencyManagement>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.1</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

I have asterisked few parts.
The parent BOM has a *parent* element in its POM as below:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.M4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

### Progress

From the spring 2.1.0 M1 release notes (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1.0-M1-Release-Notes) I see that Bean Overriding has been disabled.

The error goes away when I add a property *allow-bean-definition-overriding: true* in my application.yml file but then I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 115 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient
        ... 115 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/netty/http/client/HttpClient
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [9 skipped]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your application is mixing two incompatible versions of Spring Boot.

Your main `pom.xml` seems to be importing `spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty` with the `2.0.5.RELEASE` version.

1. You should not override versions of Spring Boot libraries, as it's all taken care of by the dependency management in the parent POM
2. You don't need the reactor-netty starter at all, as it's transitively brought by the webflux one.

Comment: Marked as right answer.
Now, I am using two annotations on a jpa test class:
'@DataJpaTest' and 
'@SpringBootTest'.

Both of these annotations bring along '@BootStrapWith' annotation and I get a mulitple bootstrap annotations error.
Could you tell me how can I possibly resolve this ?

Comment: you're not supposed to use both annotations at the same time. If you want more information about that, please create a new question with some more details.

Comment: Done. Here's the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966139/datajpatest-springboottest-in-spring-boot-2-1-0-m4

Answer (score 3):

Please don't change Spring Boot version once your project is in between development. Try to add latest version when you start project. Once development started don't change any thing in version. I have faced same problem and wasted 4-5 hours and again went back to previous version everything working perfectly.

Delete .project file and update maven.