# The bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' already registered

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have defined a trivial SpringBoot Hibernate app, copy-pasted from sample code found in a random site on the Internet. The hopefully relevant portions of my `spring.xml` look like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
... details ommitted ...

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
... details ommitted ...

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Why do I get this error?

> The bean
>   'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor',
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class],
>   could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been
>   defined in null and overriding is disabled.

**Other things I have already tried**

- Using `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager` - same error
- Using `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager` - same error
- Removing the `transactionManager` bean - ok my SpringBoot app works but now all my JUnit tests break

Comment: Maybe check this answer, I was getting the same error after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.x from 1.5.xx : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367566/trouble-when-changing-spring-boot-version-from-2-0-3-release-to-2-1-0-build-snap

Comment: Came here after trying to migrate from SpringBoot 1.5.9 to 2.2.1. Trying @lincolnadym link...